# Vaadin 23 Resynchronizing UI by client's request - If you are using push with a proxy, make sure the push timeout smaller proxy connection timeout

Tags: nginx, websocket, vaadin, vaadin-flow, vaadin23

From time to time I still receive the following error:

```
c.v.f.s.communication.ServerRpcHandler   : Resynchronizing UI by client's request. A network message was lost before reaching the client and the client is reloading the full UI state. This typically happens because of a bad network connection with packet loss or because of some part of the network infrastructure (load balancer, proxy) terminating a push (websocket or long-polling) connection. If you are using push with a proxy, make sure the push timeout is set to be smaller than the proxy connection timeout
```

I use NGINX as a proxy and Spring Boot with Vaadin application.
Could you please explain what properties in NGINX and Vaadin responsible for:

```
If you are using push with a proxy, make sure the push timeout is set to be smaller than the proxy connection timeout
```

What property at NGINX configuration responsible for `push timeout` or `proxy connection timeout` and the same for Vaadin application.

In Vaadin application I use:

```
@Push(transport = Transport.LONG_POLLING)
```

Right now I'm playing with different properties but without any success, so I'll really appreciate your guidance on this. Thanks!

Comment: If you have more than one node, and using iphash method to achieve "sticky sessions" behavior, you need to set also "max_fails" to 0 in nginx, Otherwise random timeout failure from server will black list it and next request is not going to right server and it will lead to this error in Vaadin. Alternatively in one node scenario it can be the too short proxy timeout as you suspect.

Comment: Check proxy timeout out config hints in nginx here: https://ubiq.co/tech-blog/increase-request-timeout-nginx/

Comment: Thanks! Right now I configured `vaadin.pushLongPollingSuspendTimeout=50000 vaadin.maxMessageSuspendTimeout=7000` for Vaadin app, and `proxy_read_timeout 300;   proxy_connect_timeout 300;   proxy_send_timeout 300;` Monitoring the application right now

Comment: @Klaus no, unfortunately some unknown issues are still present - https://github.com/vaadin/flow/issues/16664